# <DIV> wrap differences between IE11 and Chrome/FF

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer-11

Simply check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ny4cddao/11/) with IE 11 and then with Chrome and FireFox

I've this HTML

```
<div style="width:120px;background-color:#EE1111;">
<div class="daytext"><b>27</b></div>
<div class="dayitem">
    <div class="dayzoneon">M</div>
    <div class="dayzoneon">P</div>
    <div class="dayzoneoff">S</div>
    <div class="dayzoneon">N</div>
</div>
<div class="daytext"><b>28</b></div>
<div class="dayitem">
    <div class="nozone"></div>
</div>
<div class="daytext"><b>29</b></div>
<div class="dayitem">
    <div class="dayzoneon">M</div>
    <div class="dayzoneon">P</div>
    <div class="dayzoneoff">S</div>
    <div class="dayzoneon">N</div>
</div>
</div>
```

that in IE is wrapped correctly, so the "29" box go to the "next line" hover the other , instead in Chrome/FF even if the "29"  is "out" of container  it's put on the "same line" anyway.

This is the CSS of "29"

```
.daytext{
position: absolute;
font-size: large;
top:10;
left: 10;
width:48px;
background-color: #333333;
border-radius:5px !important;
margin: 2px;
opacity: 0.7;
height:32px;
text-align:center;
z-index: 2;
padding-top:12px;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: inline-block;
}
```

I googled for so long without finding answers...

Another strange thing is that if I add

```
overflow:hidden
```

to the first  the "29" box should disappear, instead it's still visible

I'm thinking that IE11 set implicitly some CSS property or it has some property's default value different from Chrome/FF

Comment: a downvote without comment ? really helpful man =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parent container has the default position `static`  as of that it does not act as *containing block* and the `overflow: hidden` has no effect to your `absolute` positioned elements. You could add `position: relative` or `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to the element and it will behave as *containing block*.

You specify `top:10;` and `left:10;` which are both invalid values as they don't have a unit, because of that their default values  `top: auto` and `left: auto` are used. But in that case the element itself would act as if it is positioned `static` but it won't use any space in the flow because its position is actually `absolute`. That why your `29` element should not be moved to the next line (for the text flow it has no width).

So in my opinion IE is wrong about that, and the result Chrome and FireFox are showing are right.

To be honest i don't have an IE right here, so I can't test myself. It might be a font size/render issue. If you increase the width of the container, does the `29` stay in the second line until it will completely fit into the first line?

Comment: partial solution, but you gave me important info useful to put me on the right track, thanks